# Form data not being taken by SQL Update

Tags: c#, sql

I asked a question earlier, still not solved so I apologise is this breaks a rule of opening a new question etc.

this command;

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringUserData"].ConnectionString);
connection.Open();

string updateSQL = "UPDATE userData SET [First Name] = @FirstName , [Last Name] = @LastName ,  [Display Name] = @DisplayName , [Phone Number] = @PhoneNumber , [Mobile Number] = @MobileNumber , [Date of Birth] = @DoB , AddressNumber = @AddNumber , AddressRoadName = @AddRoad , AddressTown = @AddTown , AddressCity = @AddCity , AddressCounty = @AddCounty , AddressPostCode = @AddPostCode WHERE (ID = @ID)";
SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand(updateSQL, connection);
update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", userID);
update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", firstname.Text);
update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", lastname.Text);
...
update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddCounty", addressCounty.Text);
update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddPostCode", addressPostCode.Text);
update.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

is not taking the values from firstname.Text, lastname.Text etc when I click the save button (where this command is executed). i've debugged it and its simply taking "" when there is clearly text in the text box. I do load the values from the database when the page loads (page load can be found here; pastebin.com/sbscTg8x), im not sure if this is the cause.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: can you post the full save click event?

Comment: @raja that is essentially it, the page load can be found here; http://pastebin.com/sbscTg8x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usual error in `Page_Load`. You don't have a test for [Page.IsPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

In ASP.NET, the code in `Page_Load` is executed every time you need to run code on the server side.  If you click a button, before the code for the button click, a new Page_Load event is raised.
If you don't put a check for

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
  // code that runs only the first time the page is loaded
}
```

you reexecute all the code that initializes the textboxes and the other controls, then your click code is called but, at this point, you have lost the page's user change.

Comment: ahh thanks very much, something so simple! Also, you see the way I have pulled the values from Database with near-replica code, is there as simpler way? Thanks again mate

Comment: Just noticed it, that's 12 hits to the database to retrieve values from the same table. Use just one `SELECT field1, field2, etc.. FROM table WHERE ...` then look on how to use `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()`